# EntityFramework Code-first migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, migration, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to implement a ASP.NET MVC 4 app, using Entityframework code first. Actually I have 2 data context, a custom and the default UsersContext.

```
namespace Namespace.Models
{
    public class StoreDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base("StoreDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Probably the statement `public UsersContext() : base("StoreDB")` is wrong. But when I left the default value `: base("DefaultConnection")` a `DefaultConnection` database was created, and I want, of course, just one database named "StoreDB".

I made some changed to the `UserProfile` that belong to `UsersContext`

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DoB { get; set; }
}
```

And I updated the Global.asax as follow:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new Namespace.Models.StoreDbInitializer());
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Namespace.Models.UsersContext>());
```

But when I run the application, I get this error:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Why is it trying to create the database under "master"?

My Connection string is the following:

```
<add name="StoreDB" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there are entries written to tables in the master db when adding a database to a sql server instance. That being said, if you try to create a DB you need to have permissions on the Master db. [Microsoft's master DB page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx)

Comment: Hi, but my goal is not to use master db .. I want to use mine own .. I'm already afraid that I'll have problems related to EF when I'll move to production .. if I don't have control on DB I think I would change everything :(

Comment: The master db keeps a list of all databases in the current instance. So when you connect to your DB, `StoreDB`, SQL Server will lookup the entry for that DB in the master db as well as other things like permissions (which from my understanding is not kept in the master db anymore). Basicly, you can't have a SQL Server without a master db.

Comment: From link I posted above: _The master database records all the system-level information for a SQL Server system. This includes instance-wide metadata such as logon accounts, endpoints, linked servers, and system configuration settings._ [...] _Also, master is the database that records the existence of all other databases and the location of those database files and records the initialization information for SQL Server. Therefore, SQL Server cannot start if the master database is unavailable._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem was that I was running Visual studio NOT as Administrator .. I don't know why exactly, but now seems ok.
Sorry to bother you and thanks for your time and your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the site in IIS? Is the Application Pool running under an account that can create databases in your SQL Express instance? If it's running as `ApplicationPoolIdentity` try changing it to run as `NetworkService`.

Also, Try removing the `UsersContext` and moving the property into your `StoreDB` context. You should have one context with the same name as the connection string

Comment: Hi, I'm using Cassini actually. Do I need to change something?

Comment: Why do you have 2 contexts? Do you have 2 databases?

Comment: No, just one DB. One context has been created automatically by MVC (for Users), the other has been created by me following a tutorial. I admit that I'm mew in MVC 4 and EF so probably my architecture is wrong

Comment: Try removing the `UsersContext` and moving the property into your `StoreDB` context. You should have one context with the same name as the connection string

Comment: No probs - please accept the answer if you're happy with it! Will update it with that info

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's ignoring the fact that you have a connection string named "StoreDB" and it's trying to create a database named that instead (that's another function of the same constructor you are calling).

You can explicitly tell the constructor that this is the name of a connection string like so:

```
public UsersContext() : base("name=StoreDB")
...
```

Try that and let me know if it works.